# Incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘int [2]’

Tags: arduino

In Arduino I have an error.

> incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘int [2]’

```cpp
long received;
long received_t;
long received_m;
int arra[2];

void setup() {
    analogReference(INTERNAL);
    Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {
     while( Serial.available() > 0) {
         arra = Serial.read();
         Serial.println(arra[0]);
         Serial.println(arra[1]);
     }
}
```

Comment: `Serial.read()` returns a single integer.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
 while( Serial.available() > 1) {
     arra[0] = Serial.read();
     arra[1] = Serial.read();
     Serial.println(arra[0]);
     Serial.println(arra[1]);
 }
```

?

Still not good code, but should at least compile.